# Minimum moves for puzzle using induction

Tags: proof-writing, induction

Prove that the minimum number of moves required to solve a Tower of Hanoi puzzle with $n$ pieces equals $2^n-1$.

```
Proof: use induction
    Base case: set n = 1. (2^1)-1 = 1. Clearly  a puzzle with 1 piece only needs 1 move.
    Inductive step: Let n >= 1.
                    Suppose a puzzle with n pieces will take (2^n)-1 moves.
                    Want to show that a puzzle with n+1 pieces will take (2^n+1)-1 moves.
```

I'm not sure where to go from here in terms of proving the n+1 scenario...

Comment: What is the puzzle???? .... my bet is Towers of Hanoi, but you should really add this!

Comment: @Bram28 It is Towers of Hanoi. I will add it to the question

Comment: ...big surprise there ...:)

Answer (score 1):

HINT

As with all your previous induction proofs you have been posting today, the key is to decompose the '$n+1$ case' into the '$n$ case' ... do you see how you can reduce the task of moving s stack of $n+1$ pieces into one or more tasks of moving a stack of $n$ pieces?

Comment: uhhhh what? I'm confused I don't get what you're saying

Comment: @DestinyCoots OK, suppose you could move a whole stack of $n$ pieces in one move ... how many moves would it take to solve the puzzle with $n+1$ pieces?

Comment: it would still be one move...

Comment: @DestinyCoots No, it's not *any* $n$ ... OK, how about this: suppose that in addition to moving $1$ piece at a time, you are also allowed to move a stack of $5$ pieces in $1$ move ... then how many moves does it take to solve the puzzle with $6$ pieces?

Comment: well then it would be two moves. You move the stack of 5 then the extra 1 piece. Am I misinterpreting what you are trying to say?

Comment: @DestinyCoots where would you move that stack of $5$ pieces to?

Answer (score 0):

Your base case is correct. Then you assume it is correct for $n$ pieces. Then notice that when you have $n+1$ pieces, you have to solve the $n$ pieces of the tower first in order to get to the biggest piece (the piece on the bottom) with $2^n-1$ moves by inductive assumption. Then you move the biggest piece to its proper place with $1$ move so now you did $2^n-1+1 = 2^n$ moves. Then you solve the puzzle for the remaining $n$ pieces again with $2^n-1$. So totally, you make $2^n+2^n-1 = 2*2^n-1 = 2^{n+1}-1$ moves. Then by induction, your argument holds for all $n$.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose there are n rings on one "tower" A and you want to move them to "tower" B.  In order to do that, you have to get to a position where the largest ring is the only one left on "A" and "B" is completely empty.  That is, you must have first move all n-1 smaller rings to "C".  So, writing T(n) the number of moves necessary to move n rings, we must first move n rings from "A" to "C", T(n) moves, then move that last ring to "B", one move, and then move the n rings from "C" to "A", another T(n) moves.  That is T(n+1)= T(n)+ 1+ T(n)= 2T(n)+ 1.

To prove that $T(n)= 2^n- 1$, first note that with n= 1 we need only move the one ring from "A" to "B", $T(1)= 2^1- 1= 1$.  With n= k+ 1, $T(k+1)= 2T(n)+ 1= 2(2^n- 1)+ 1= 2^{n+1}- 2+ 1= 2^{n+1}- 1$